# making tomcat manager application multi-user

Tags: tomcat

I want to use the tomcat in a multi-user environment. What this means is that I want it to be used by multiple users for deploying their applications. They'll use the manager application for deployment of their applications. But each user should only be able to view applications deployed by this user without interfering into other user's applications. I tried to do this by configuring multiple users in tomcat-users.xml but have not found a solution so far. Is it possible to do something like this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure that it is not possible to define such fine grained access rights to tomcats manager app.

I would users have their own tomcat instance. Unfortunately this is much more complex:

1. you have to create and configure the instances
2. your machine needs some more resources
3. if all applications should be available at one http port you have to define some proxy (this is quite easy using Apache httpd and mod_proxy_*)

But at the end you have your users well separated. I don't think this is possible using only one tomcat instance.

Comment: Thanks Magomi. The idea was to limit the resources by using it in a multi user manner. I guess writing my own manager application on the lines of tomcat manager could be a possible solution. Thereby I could maintain a record of users and their application and allow actions accordingly. I think I should be able to use the services that the tomcat manager application uses underneath from my customer manager. Any thoughts on such an approach?